# Normalize data without losing confidence interval of reference

Tags: r, confidence-interval, normalization

I have a small data frame of lower and upper confidence levels along with means.
What I would like to do is compare the means of all rows directly against the first.

Here is the DF:

```
       upper     mean    lower phase
st1 16592.40 16511.10 16429.80    p1
st2 18782.72 18740.79 18698.85    p2
st3 17819.98 17779.84 17739.71    p3
st4 20556.09 20493.97 20431.86    p4
st5 21869.28 21805.69 21742.09    p5
st6 22409.64 22348.77 22287.90    p6

suppose what I'm looking for is something like

       upper     mean    lower phase
st1     0.8       1.1    1    p1
st2     0.9       1.3   1.2   p2
st3     0.85      1.35  1.25  p3
st4     1.05      1.42  1.4   p4
st5     1.1       1.33  1.5   p5
st6     1.2       1.4   1.55  p6

(these are not the real values, just showing how each value should be compared to the mean of the first row's mean)
```

So I would need the mean of the first row to be '1', and the mean of the other rows to be relative to this row (so 1.2, 0.95, etc), but the upper and lower CIs also need to be transformed, so just dividing each row by row 1 would not work because then row 1 itself would have a mean of 1, and upper and lower estimate of 1.

For the means, I could divide each row by row 1, but then what about the CI values?

RepEx:

```
structure(list(upper = c(16592.3993885356, 18782.7217488299, 
17819.9807713548, 20556.0852007733, 21869.2802347753, 22409.6377843991
), mean = c(16511.099, 18740.788, 17779.843, 20493.974, 21805.685, 
22348.769), lower = c(16429.7986114644, 18698.8542511701, 17739.7052286452, 
20431.8627992267, 21742.0897652247, 22287.9002156009), phase = c("p1", 
"p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6")), row.names = c("st1", "st2", "st3", 
"st4", "st5", "st6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's unclear why you need to perform this division, but because it's tantamount to a change of units, you are free to divide *all* values by any nonzero number you like.  Use the mean of the first line.